# how to generate a random and then not show that random again

Tags: c#, list

I'm writing a card game in C#, a game of blackjack, where the user presses a button and it deals a card, the value of that card gets added to a text box. If the value of the text box goes over 21 the user has lost.

I'm having a problems with the dealing of the cards, i generate a random, say 5 gets generated show the 5 of diamonds, add the value of the 5 of diamonds to the score text box and display a picture box(the 5 of diamonds playing card). However once 5 has been generated i'm having problems not generating that card again, i have the logic down of what needs to happen, i'm just not sure on the actual code itself as i'm a beginner.

So far iv tried 2 different ways, a List and a array of Boolean values and i'm still struggling, could anybody point me in the right direction in terms of code.

```
List<int> Diamonds = new List<int>();
        Random random = new Random();
        genRandom = random.Next(0, 5);


        while (Diamonds.Contains(genRandom))
        {
            genRandom = random.Next(0, 5);
            break;
        } 


        while (!Diamonds.Contains(genRandom))

        if (genRandom == 0)
        {
            Diamonds.add(0);
            score = score += 2;
            scoreTextBox.Text = score.ToString();
            diamonds2.Show();

        }
```

Thanks in advance, sorry about the bad grammar!

Comment: Instead of generating 1 random number at a time here is another solution. Put all the possible cards in a list and then shuffle that list. Then you can pick the cards starting and the beginning of the list. Just like you would if you were playing actual cards.

Comment: Why do you have that break in the while? That'll stop the loop immediately. Remove it and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

I would take the reverse approach, by creating a collection that holds all the possible cards, and then draw them from the collection randomly.

Say you have a class called `Deck`, which represents a card deck. Fill it with `Card` classes. Now when you start drawing cards, randomly pick a number in the collection and remove that card from the `Deck`. The next time the same random number is drawn, it will draw a different card from the deck, since you remove the used cards.

Just remember to generate a random number that is within bounds of the size of the deck, which will decrease after each draw.

Comment: Basically, LightStriker has the same answer with some example code which should work fine.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you have right now is that you don't have a card pool. You should have a list of card you can draw from and once a card is picked, it is removed from the available choices and cannot be drawn again.

```
List<Card> deck = new List<Card>();

deck.Add(new Card(1, CardType.Diamonds));
deck.Add(new Card(2, CardType.Diamonds));

...

Card nextCard = deck[Random.Next(0, deck.Count - 1)];
deck.Remove(nextCard);
```

where:

```
struct Card
{
    public int number;
    public CardType type;

    public Card(int number, CardType type)
    {
        this.number = number;
        this.type = type;
    }
}

enum CardType
{
    Diamonds,
    Spades,
    Hearts,
    Clubs
}
```

It's a very simplistic, object oriented approach where each card is clearly defined as a unique container. It might not be the most optimal way, but probably much easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks man i'm going to give this a try, although is that all not a bit complicated, say i was not making a card game but i still was generating 52 numbers where each number did a different action on an if statement would there not be a way to remove that number from the range of randoms generated or if that random was generated again don't do anything just generate a new number? Thanks again in advance

Comment: Whether it is cards, ints, doubles or whatever, if you can add them to a collection, you can remove them again.

Comment: @Angelo109: You simply have to replace `List<Card>` for `List<int>` and you end up with a list of 52 numbers that you can add or remove. A List allow you to add or remove item by their index or by their identity.

Comment: @LightStriker I'm still having problems with my code i have a list of integers 0 - 12 and a random which is my list.count then an if statement for each of my possible numbers generated by the random (0 - 12, as you probably gathered lol :P ) say 0 gets generated i have an if statement if(random == 0) basically show a card add the value of that card to a score box then list.remove(0) however 0 can still be generated by the random do i need to return the list to update it or something like that? again sorry for the bad grammar and thanks in advance!

Comment: 0 can still be generated, but it's the index of the list, not the item itself. If you remove the int "0" from the list, the int now being at index 0 should be "1". It's why using "Card" instead of "int" is easier to understand. If I remove the card at index 0, which can be Ace of Spade, then Ace of Spade cannot be picked again even if random is 0 again because the card at index 0 is now another card.

Comment: @LightStriker, iv been looking over this code and iv made a class with 3 properties an int, a picture box and a bool. Iv also made a list and a random generator im struggling with this code you have put on here, how would i actually show the picturebox and add the value of the card and then not have that card shown again?

Comment: @Angelo109 I've read your comment a few times and cannot understand exactly what is your problem. One problem at a time... Show the picturebox where? A form?

Comment: @LightStriker yes sorry i have a number of pictureboxes on a form all hidden when the form starts, when the deal button gets pressed a random number gets generated, im struggling on the code, so that when the random is generated i want it to "deal" the card at that place in the list, which means i want to .Show() the picturebox and add the value of the card to the users score then remove the card from the pack. I have a list of Cards all with an int and a picturebox and a bool (ignore the bool for the time being) what would the code look like to "Deal" the card? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Angelo109 I think you will have to post other question here, more specific. However, if I had to do it, I could derive the "card" class from PictureBox. `public class Card : PictureBox` Would be easier to handle them this way.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that the most i use it is as follows:

```
List<int> available = new List<int>(5000);
for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)
available.Add(i);
```

The above code will generate all random numbers.

Now you can choose from them as follows:

```
List<int> result = new List<int>(5000);
while(available.Count > 0)
{
 int index = random.Next(availableCount);
 result.Add(available[index]);
 available.RemoveAt(index);
}
return result;
```

Since you are removing after getting they will never repeat.

Comment: I saw this approach in my algorithms class, works very well, no performance overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
List<int> Diamonds = new List<int>();
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) //10 is just an example..dk how many cards :P
{
    Diamonds.Add(i);
}

Random random = new Random();
int index = random.Next(0, Diamonds.Count - 1);
int nr = Diamonds[index];
Diamonds.Remove(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do would be to sort the entire list randomly (by sorting by `Rand() - 0.5`), then each time you want a 'random' card, take the first one and remove it from the list. The cards are in a random order so it's the same effect statistically as picking a random one each time, and you won't pick the same card twice in a given game.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this conceptually is to have an array which represents a deck of cards, and then deal cards from it.

Ideally you would use a stack for this, but unfortunately you can't shuffle a stack!

Therefore, your best bet is to use a `List<Card>`, where 'Card' is a class that represents a card. The `Card` class would have two properties: a `Suite` and a rank from 1 (the Ace) to 13 where 11 is Jack, 12 is Queen and 13 is King.

You would populate your `List<Card>` deck with all 52 possible cards, and then you could shuffle it using an implementation of the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Here's a complete sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var deck = new List<Card>();

            for (int rank = 1; rank <= 13; ++rank)
                foreach (Suite suite in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suite)))
                    deck.Add(new Card {Rank = rank, Suite = suite});

            var shuffler = new Shuffler();

            shuffler.Shuffle(deck);

            // Deal the top 10 cards.

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
                Console.WriteLine(deck[i]);
        }
    }

    public enum Suite
    {
        Clubs,
        Diamonds,
        Hearts,
        Spades
    }

    public sealed class Card
    {
        public Suite Suite;
        public int Rank;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string rank;

            switch (Rank)
            {
                case 1:  rank = "Ace";   break;
                case 11: rank = "Jack";  break;
                case 12: rank = "Queen"; break;
                case 13: rank = "King";  break;
                default: rank = Rank.ToString(); break;
            }

            return string.Format("{0} of {1}", rank, Suite);
        }
    }

    public sealed class Shuffler
    {
        public Shuffler()
        {
            _rng = new Random();
        }

        public void Shuffle<T>(IList<T> array)
        {
            for (int n = array.Count; n > 1; )
            {
                int k = _rng.Next(n);
                --n;
                T temp = array[n];
                array[n] = array[k];
                array[k] = temp;
            }
        }

        private readonly Random _rng;
    }
}
```

Real code should validate Rank and Suite, of course. Also, you'd be better off writing a Deck class which encapsulated shuffling and dealing (it could remove cards from the end of the `List<Card>` when dealing).